# Why is NuGet installing the wrong version of Identity.Core in my WebProject?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

So I am trying to install Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core v2.1 in my web project. I have an Identity Project as well.

```
Solution
    - Identity
    - Web
```

When I run (from package manager console)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
```

targeting the identity project, NuGet installs version 2.1 into the project.
When I run the same command on the web project, NuGet installs version 1.0.

I uninstalled the package, deleted the entry in the packages.Config file / web.config and removed the folder from the packages folder in the directory structure, Cleaned the solution and tried again.

Same result.

I manually deleted the reference, deleted the entry in the packages.Config file / web.config and verified the folder from the packages folder in the directory structure was not there, cleaned the solution, verified that the dll in the Identity project (bo the dll in the folder structure and in the properties in the solution explorer in Visual Studio were the correct version, and then installed the reference manually from there.

Same result.

I restarted my computer (because why not). Tried again. Same result.

It seems that no matter what I do the Web project refuses to install any version above 1.0.

Any Suggestions?

UPDATE 1:

I have since done the same with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework since the two are coupled.

The same result.

UPDATE 2:

As requested

```
<packages>
  <package id="Angular.UI.Bootstrap" version="0.11.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="angularjs" version="1.2.17" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="DataAnnotationsExtensions" version="1.1.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3" version="1.1.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Dinheiro.GoogleAnalytics" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Elmah.MVC" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="FontAwesome" version="4.0.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="GMC.CustomerInfo" version="2.2.7.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="GMCLogger" version="1.1.23" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="GMCServicesCore" version="2.0.234" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="LinqKit" version="1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.1.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.7.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5" version="4.4.14" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5.Core" version="4.4.14" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web" version="4.4.14" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.MVC3" version="3.2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Postal" version="0.9.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="WebActivator" version="1.2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Looks like v2.1.0 is installed to me. What's the issue?

Comment: Error 10 Assembly 'Identity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e3

Comment: @Kiliman Despite everything I have done it won't install a higher version than 1.0 in references

Comment: Seems like an issue with your project and not NuGet. Uninstall the package then look in the .csproj file to see if there are any leftover traces. Then re-install the package. As a last resort, simply reference the 2.1.0 assembly explicitly.

Comment: @Kiliman removing it from csproj then reinstalling fixed it. Would you mind changing your answer to that and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. I just tried installing the package *Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core* and NuGet installed v2.1.0. I  had to explicitly specify -Version 1.0.0 to have it install the older one.

Have you tried explicitly specifying the version you want?

What version of NuGet do you have installed?

What type of Web project do you have?

Can you post your *packages.config* file?

**UPDATE**

Seems like an issue with your project and not NuGet. Uninstall the package then look in the .csproj file to see if there are any leftover traces. Then re-install the package. As a last resort, simply reference the 2.1.0 assembly explicitly.

Comment: I have added the requested file

Comment: I don't see it. Also can you answer the other questions?

Comment: Yes, 2.8, Class Library,